# Jump script in bge

Tags: python, game-engine

for a school project I'm working on a simple game. I want to make the character jump using the `KX_CharacterWrapper`. (it's necessary to use python since the project is about coding a game)

For the same character, I have a movements script using `walkDirection` which works fine but the character just won't jump.

```
import bge


def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner
    me = bge.constraints.getCharacter(own)
    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard

    me.gravity = 9.81
    me.maxJumps = 1
    cont.jump_speed = 2

    if keyboard.events[bge.events.SPACEKEY] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
        me.jump()
main()
```

I assume the jump function works differently since the rest of the script like gravity works but I couldn't find an example. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think cont.jump_speed should be me.jump_speed, but as I did not find jump_speed in the documentation I suggest you visit this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JKH_NROh9g) that contains a motion script and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import bge

def main():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner
    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard.events

    if keyboard[bge.events.SPACEKEY]==1:
        bge.types.KX_CharacterWrapper.jump(bge.constraints.getCharacter(own)) 
        # make sure the object has "Character"  as Physics Type      

main()
```

I recently discover that piece of code and it works just great. Hopefully works for you as well

Comment: Thanks for that, it was what I was looking for, and it worked very well.